# For a given (non trivial) zero of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta$, why does $\zeta(1/2 + \operatorname{Im}(z))$ approximately equal $1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> For a given (non trivial) zero of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta$, why does $\zeta(1/2 + \operatorname{Im}(z))$ approximately equal $1$?

I was putting some known nontrivial zeros of the zeta function into WolframAlpha. However, when I tried removing the $i$ from the imaginary part, I realized the result was very close to $1$. I feel this probably is a corollary of the Riemann hypothesis, but I cannot find any papers that state this. Is there any way to show that this is true, or a corollary of any other conjecture?

Comment: Because $\zeta (c) \to 1, c>0$ large and the remainder should be on the order of $2^{(1-c)}/(c-1)$ so decrease very fast even for $c=14$ which is the first non trivial RZ; the result is true for any positive number, nothing to do with imaginary parts of the zeroes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a property of the fact that, for *all* large real $s$, $\zeta(s)$ is approximately $1$. You can see this from the definition
$$\zeta(s)=1+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\cdots;$$
for large $s$, the $\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\cdots$ consists of terms that are quite small, and so $\zeta(s)$ is approximately $1$. In fact, one can show that
$$1\leq \zeta(s)\leq 1+\frac{\sqrt2}{2^s}$$
for all $s\geq 4$. So, when $s=\frac12+t$ where $\frac12+it$ is a nontrivial zero of $\zeta$,
$$1\leq \zeta(s)\leq 1+2^{-t};$$
since the first nontrivial zero of $\zeta$ is about $\frac12+14.135i$, the $2^{-t}$ term is very small.